# Create MPEG-DASH Initialization segment

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, adaptive-bitrate, mp4box

I am looking to convert between HLS and MPEG Dash.  I do not access to the original fully concatenated video file, only the individual HLS segments.

In doing this transformation to MPEG Dash I need to supply an initialziation segment for the Dash manifest .mpd file.

My questions are:

1. What is the structure of a Dash video initialization segment?
2. How can I generate/create one without the need for the original full file?

**Perhaps a solution would involve getting `MP4Box` to convert the '.ts' HLS segments to Dash '.m4s' segments which are self initializing, but I am unsure how to go about this this?**

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE: 
Snippet to stream using original hls segments.  Video plays all the way through but is just black.**

```
  <Representation width="426" height="238" frameRate="25" id="238p 400kbps" bandwidth="400000">
    <SegmentList timescale="25000" duration="112500">
           <SegmentURL media="video_0_400000/hls/segment_0.ts"/>
           <SegmentURL media="video_0_400000/hls/segment_1.ts"/>
          <SegmentURL media="video_0_400000/hls/segment_2.ts"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the structure of a Dash video initialization segment?

The initialization segment contains information required to initialize the video decoder. The initialization segment is optional (refer to ISO/IEC 23009-1).

For [ISO BMFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_base_media_file_format) (commonly known as mp4) this includes the `moov` box (specified in ISO/IEC 14496-12). For [MPEG-TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) usually there is no initialization segment. When present it contains several packets that carry the initialization data in a [PES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packetized_elementary_stream).

> How can I generate/create one without the need for the original full file?

Converting `HLS` to `MPEG-DASH` is trivial if your target player supports the required features. First you need a player that supports MPEG-TS. Then you don't actually need an initialization segment because the initialization data is contained inside each HLS segment. To convert and HLS playlist to a MPEG-DASH mpd you have to create a `segment list` or a `segment template`. Here is an example:

HLS:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.0,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
stream2.ts
```

MPD:

```
...
<SegmentList duration="10">
   <SegmentURL media="stream0.ts"/>
   <SegmentURL media="stream1.ts"/>
   <SegmentURL media="stream2.ts"/>
</SegmentList>
...
```

If your target player does not support MPEG-TS or `SegmentList` then you have to convert the HLS stream to MPEG-DASH by the use of some external tool like `MP4Box`.

Comment: Many thanks, this is really insightful. I don't believe I have a player which will support these HLS segments.  Could you point me in the right direction for the mp4box command that will do this conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had much experience with mp4box. I've tried it a couple of times but I don't remember the exact commands. I suggest you examine the  [documentation](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/).

Comment: Using the SegmentList method above, I can play the video but the video is black all the way through.  I have added the snippet at the end of the original post.