# Whats the init.mp4 and how can I create it?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, type-conversion, mpeg-dash

I was looking for exactly this [question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485759/combine-mpeg-dash-segments-ex-init-mp4-segments-m4s-back-to-a-full-source-m), but I still don't get it...

The only files I have are the segments.m4s but still want to create a "source.mp4"

Comment: You can’t without the init. The init has information required to decode the video.

Comment: This is what it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595036/create-mpeg-dash-initialization-segment .. if you lost it, you might get lucky using another one from a video with the exact same properties